# How to prevent text compression when centering a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

See attached:

[Squished `Toggle` in SwiftUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W1U4.png)

... The code for this centered toggle is simply:

```
@State var rememberMe: Bool = false

HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Spacer()
    Toggle(
        "Remember Me",
        isOn: $rememberMe
    )
    Spacer()
}
```

Obviously, there's no need for ellipsis here, but by eliminating the `Spacer()` on each side, it'll grow to fill the width.

How do you center the `Toggle` without squishing its text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fixedSize()` seems to fix the issue on my end. We don't even need a `HStack`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rememberMe: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(
            "Remember Me",
            isOn: $rememberMe
        ).fixedSize()
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

> Result

[image: result]

[From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toggle/3277263-fixedsize):

> `fixedSize()` Fixes this view at its ideal size.

Comment: That's great, thank you! It looks like it's also possible to avoid text from squishing vertically like this: `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`